# Since the DS recordset contains all of the child's Key Signing Key, wouldn't the DS recordset be massive and difficult to load for verification?

Tags: dns, dns-domain, dnssec

I'm learning about DNSSEC today but I don't quite understand about how a parent zone would store all of its child's Key Signing Keys (DNSKEY `257`) in its `DS` record set.

As far as I understand, if I have a subdomain, say, `subdomain.icann.org`, which can have its own DNSSEC records, the `DS` record of `icann.org` will have to include the hash of the public Key Signing Key of the private key used for signing records in `subdomain.icann.org`.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
icann.org.      3600    IN  DS  18060 7 2 6BE021818B9F10ED981A03ACBF74F01E31FB15C58680AD0C4BAA464B F37A7523
icann.org.      3600    IN  DS  17248 7 2 885CF8A6CF35FD5C619E1D48B59AFB23063BBA9FEC52FF25F99094CB A10910A2
icann.org.      3600    IN  DS  23584 7 2 AF57A492640102809209AA005B93C32B7ACC83734BC785CFA50B5168 8299CD61
```

Then, for a TLD like `icann.org`, its parent zone, `.org`, will include in its `DS` record set the public Key Signing Key used by `icann.org`. This implies that `.org` "trusts" `icann.org` and this also allows the domain to be verified through the chain of trust.

However, there are so many `.org` domains out there. Then, I have 2 questions in mind:

1. Wouldn't this mean that the `DS` record set in `.org` would be an extremely huge list of its child Key Signing Key hashes?
2. I presume the chain of trust verification process goes like this:

   - Verification Process:

     1. Retrieve all Key Signing Key hashes listed in the DS record of `.org`
     2. Hash the Key Signing Key of `icann.org`
     3. Check if the hash is in the list of DS records from `.org`
   - Wouldn't this be insane if there were billions of `.org` domains all with their own Key Signing Keys? The resolver will have to load the giant list of that `DS` record set from the parent zone just to check if a Key Signing Key of `icann.org` is trusted by `.org`?

Interestingly, I did a quick check with `dig DS org` and I notice that there is *only* 1 DS record!

```
$ dig DS org                               

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> DS org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7527
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;org.               IN  DS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
org.            68568   IN  DS  26974 8 2 4FEDE294C53F438A158C41D39489CD78A86BEB0D8A0AEAFF14745C0D 16E1DE32

;; Query time: 16 msec
```

Then, how does the resolver even verify if a Key Signing Key of its child zones is trusted with only that one single hash in the `DS` record of the `.org` most parent zone?

What did I misunderstand about DNSSEC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm learning about DNSSEC today but I don't quite understand about how a parent zone would store all of its child's Key Signing Keys (DNSKEY 257) in its DS record set.

There is one `DS` record per DNSKEY (KSK) + hashing algorithm. So typically, for one KSK and one hashing algorithm, that makes one record.

For strenght and forward compatibility lots of parents hash with two algorithms (like SHA-1 and SHA-256) so in normal operations (one KSK) that means two `DS` records.

In case of preparation of KSK rollover or in the middle of it, there would be two `DNSKEY` (for KSK), hence twice the number of `DS` records, so typically 4.

A `DS` record has the hash of the key, so it is small.

> As far as I understand, if I have a subdomain, say, subdomain.icann.org, which can have its own DNSSEC records, the DS record of icann.org will have to include the hash of the public Key Signing Key of the private key used for signing records in subdomain.icann.org.

Half true. This is only true is `subdomain.example.com` is **delegated** from `example.com`. If not, `subdomain.example.com` is just one record among others in the `example.com` zone and there is nothing about `DNSKEY` or `DS` records.

> Wouldn't this mean that the DS record set in .org would be an extremely huge list of its child Key Signing Key hashes?

You seem to be in the assumption that the `DS` records are all on the same name, they are not. The owner of a `DS` record is the zone name that is delegated. So if a zone has 1 million of delegations, all signed, there will be 1 million `DS` records (twice if multiple hashing algorithms, twice if multiple DNSKEY, etc.), but each one will have the corresponding zone name as owner. Note that the zone name is needed to compute the `DS` record hash value (and not only the key content).

> Interestingly, I did a quick check with dig DS org and I notice that there is only 1 DS record!

Of course, per the above. The root zone has multiple `DS` records, for all the TLDs being DNSSEC enabled (almost all, but not all), but each `DS` record is for the given TLD, there is no single `DS` record mixing everything together, that would never work (again: the hash is a combination of the name of the zone AND the `DNSKEY` - only one, the `DS` record has a "key ID" to reference a given `DNSKEY` if multiple ones).

> Then, how does the resolver even verify if a Key Signing Key of its child zones is trusted with only that one single hash in the DS record of the .org most parent zone?

In summary, and schematizing, having `www.example.com/A` to check for DNSSEC validity, a resolver has to:

- find the zone it is in (not detailing that)
- find the `RRSIG` records on `www.example.com`; if they exist, find the `DNSKEY` that generated those (if no `RRSIG` records, name is not DNSSEC validated)
- so fetch `DNSKEY` records: in case of ZSK/KSK split (majority of cases but not mandatory nor single case out there), it may have to find also `RRSIG` records of `DNSKEY` records
- once it is up to the `DNSKEY` in the zone that signs everything transitively (so a KSK), it goes to parent (`com` here) to find out if there is `DS` record matching that `DNSKEY` record, and if the cryptography works; so it ask parent for a (one or more) `DS` record on the name `example.com`; any other zone is not involved here, either there is - one or more - `DS` records at parent for this specific `example.com` zone, or there is none (in which case of course it means the delegation is not secure as not validated by DNSSEC mechanisms).
- if so, it now looks at `RRSIG` records of that specific `DS` record at parent, and start from the beginning, to find the keys in that parent zone, and the "next" `DS` records towards root, up to reaching root.

Recommendations:

- use DNSviz online: it will clearly show delegations and DNSSEC related informations (`DS` and `DNSKEY` records and how they are linked together)
- locally use `delv`, which is kind of a successor of `dig` and is tailored for DNSSEC operations. Its `+vtrace` will show you exactly how one resolver validates a given name, with all records it has to fetch, as following:

```
$ delv +vtrace icann.org @9.9.9.9
;; fetch: icann.org/A
;; validating icann.org/A: starting
;; validating icann.org/A: attempting positive response validation
;; fetch: icann.org/DNSKEY
;; validating icann.org/DNSKEY: starting
;; validating icann.org/DNSKEY: attempting positive response validation
;; fetch: icann.org/DS
;; validating icann.org/DS: starting
;; validating icann.org/DS: attempting positive response validation
;; fetch: org/DNSKEY
;; validating org/DNSKEY: starting
;; validating org/DNSKEY: attempting positive response validation
;; fetch: org/DS
;; validating org/DS: starting
;; validating org/DS: attempting positive response validation
;; fetch: ./DNSKEY
;; validating ./DNSKEY: starting
;; validating ./DNSKEY: attempting positive response validation
;; validating ./DNSKEY: verify rdataset (keyid=20326): success
;; validating ./DNSKEY: marking as secure (DS)
;; validating org/DS: in fetch_callback_dnskey
;; validating org/DS: keyset with trust secure
;; validating org/DS: resuming validate
;; validating org/DS: verify rdataset (keyid=60955): success
;; validating org/DS: marking as secure, noqname proof not needed
;; validating org/DNSKEY: in fetch_callback_ds
;; validating org/DNSKEY: dsset with trust secure
;; validating org/DNSKEY: verify rdataset (keyid=26974): success
;; validating org/DNSKEY: marking as secure (DS)
;; validating icann.org/DS: in fetch_callback_dnskey
;; validating icann.org/DS: keyset with trust secure
;; validating icann.org/DS: resuming validate
;; validating icann.org/DS: verify rdataset (keyid=10821): success
;; validating icann.org/DS: marking as secure, noqname proof not needed
;; validating icann.org/DNSKEY: in fetch_callback_ds
;; validating icann.org/DNSKEY: dsset with trust secure
;; validating icann.org/DNSKEY: no DNSKEY matching DS
;; validating icann.org/DNSKEY: verify rdataset (keyid=18060): success
;; validating icann.org/DNSKEY: marking as secure (DS)
;; validating icann.org/A: in fetch_callback_dnskey
;; validating icann.org/A: keyset with trust secure
;; validating icann.org/A: resuming validate
;; validating icann.org/A: verify rdataset (keyid=43109): success
;; validating icann.org/A: marking as secure, noqname proof not needed
; fully validated
icann.org.      600 IN  A   192.0.43.7
icann.org.      600 IN  RRSIG   A 7 2 600 20230420040745 20230330014551 43109 icann.org. ZlywQfipe8weEimV/PO7L3uGoXqDMUoIfVs9Dr4Za0OYEGu2os2IDF/3 MWqLNCZzQ+2fdGBFCj46Prg5w53DvnWa7YTWYk9NdYMI31DuPxyYR9lo 3kfZM3scucyebCt6SmQ0fR8dq+Dq4j0hYk3n+VYnntTxRTr/fw2o8Fo7 bmg=
```

Note that a validating resolver can be top down (starting with `DS` record at root + the local hardcoded trust anchor) until reaching the requested name (or an error in the path) or bottom up (specially if parts of the answer still exist in cache, and only revalidation is needed).